# Congratulations to anna v, our second 200k user

Tags: discussion, reputation

With nearly six thousand answers posted over her first decade with us, [anna v](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1492/anna-v) surpassed the 200,000 reputation milestone this week.  Her patient explanations, broad knowledge, and insightful writing make our community a better place.

anna v, thank you!

Comment: Congrats  !  Love her answers as they seems always to be focused on the practical and accessible to a wide audience.

Comment: Agree! Congrats! -NN

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Συγχαρητήρια!!!

Comment: Congrats! I too love her answers.  She explains things in an easy to understand manner.

Answer (score 62):

Thank you, Rob, it has been a nice trip these ten years.

I was forced to retire from research in 2000, because of civil service rules, and did not want to stay on (with various grants) because money for research in Greece was, and still is, not enough for high energy experiments. That require a number of trips to CERN and meetings to keep effective in the group work, which means my staying on would not allow the younger people to be active.

At first I got involved in the proposed global warming models, and studied the status (enough for a master's degree). When I came to the conclusion that trying to affect the global warming (yes, the globe is warming) by the imaginary knob of CO<sub>2</sub> was more or less as effective as ordering the tide to stop, I lost interest and was bored with the controversies.

Fortunately I discovered the physics.SE site and have been keeping my little white (women have white) cells working by the variety of subjects on the site, and also to learn new stuff by the many excellent answers on topics I am not familiar with.

You might have noticed that in my answers I try giving links. That is because, turning 81 in a few days, I want to make sure if I remember correctly the statements I make.

Comment: Happy upcoming birthday, as well!

Comment: That is fascinating. I shall read your excellent answers with even more enthusiasm.

Comment: Συγχαρητήρια, Anna!

Comment: I appreciate your efforts that have helped many users.